# includegraphics of PDF Image Masks the Figure's Text

Tags: graphics

I have an image I need to include in a paper.  The image was generated using Biorender.  Below is what the figure looks like in Preview on a Mac. It appears similarly in Biorender.

[image: Sequence Image]

The [image file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Gtxbzd7b9zLpqDEBqxMBPWHoGwZWXmo/view?usp=share_link) is in PDF format.

When I include the image using `graphicsx` the image is distorted where text is obscured (e.g., "Sample Preparation" in the top left, the numbers in the three circles are gone).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rna_sequencing_pipeline.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

**Latex Version**:
[image]

**Question**
What am I doing wrong when including the image that distorts the figure?

Comment: My LaTeX version look OK. Maybe a problem of your viewer ....

Comment: looks ok here. Show the log-file and put the pdf that you created somewhere for download.